# javascript not loaded in php file on nginx server

Tags: javascript, php, nginx

I set up a nginx server on a VPS, and trying to make website base on this setting. The problem I have is that the external js file (stored in server) seems cannot be loaded when accessing the php page.

This is my nginx.conf, server_name and root's name is changed for privacy reason:

```
  server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
root /var/www/example;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
  #fastcgi_pass remote_php_ip:9000;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-cgi.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi.conf;
}

location ~ \.(js|jpg|png|css)(.*)$  {
  expires 30d;
}
```

}

this is my php test page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- update aob -->
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS --> 
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="example.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.log("hello");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript, example.js, which located at the same root of the php file:

```
console.log('print something');
```

What I expect to see when I access the example.php is that the console will shows:
print something
hello

but when I access the page I only have the inline script executed. I've used the chrome inspector and I found that js file is not loaded at all, but all other CDN provided scripts can be loaded normally.

I've tried to find a solution for this, what I suspect is that my nginx.conf have something wrong, but I couldn't find any that would solve my cases. Please help.

Comment: Look closely. `scr` != `src`.

Comment: @esqew sharp observation!

Comment: @esqew I feel absolutely stupid lol, thank you so much mate!

Answer (score 0):

Found by @esqew, I wrote the

```
scr=
```

instead of

```
src=
```

After fixing everything is fine now.